# Zeitwerk, require_dependency and splitting Ruby classes into a few files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Before Rails 6 there was a simple way to split any Ruby class into multiple files without introducing any additional modules or concerns. It was quite useful for those God classes which happened to be a bit too large to be kept in one file:

```
# god.rb
class God < ApplicationRecord
  require_dependency 'god~callbacks'
  require_dependency 'god~scopes'
  require_dependency 'god~search'
  require_dependency 'god~something_else'
  require_dependency 'god~and_more'
  require_dependency 'god~and_even_more'
  ...
end

# god~callbacks.rb
class God
  before_save :nullify_blanks
  before_save :nullify_unrelated_attrs
  ...
end
```

and the file structure has looked like this:

```
models/
  god.rb
  god~callbacks.rb
  god~scopes.rb
  god~search.rb
  ...
```

And that has worked great — anytime you change anything in any of those files the changes were correctly reloaded.

Since Rails 6 a new class loader is used — the Zeitwerk. And that's great but seems that it doesn't work with `require_dependency`, at least when that method is used in such a non-typical way.

So the question is, is it possible to split a class definition into a few files and keep the auto-reloading working with Zeitwerk. And the goal is to split a class without introducing any inner modules/concerns.

And please, no need to comment on whether a 1000-line long class is a good design practice or not, that's not the point of the question.

Comment: I have never seen Ruby files with a tilde in the filename so this is a learning experience for me. I'd be really interested in knowing how you came to this practice.

Comment: Any naming convention can be used instead, tilde is convenient because it is an allowed character and is clearly different from any characters typically used in regular ruby source files, so I know that those tilde files define some aspect of a class. I use it a lot, and to me a few related files placed in the same directory is more convenient than a main file and a subdirectory with its inner modules.

Comment: I'd recommend not using `~` in a filename. The convention is either `-` or `_`. Because some characters have special meaning in a shell (`~` included) we avoid them. Yeah, it's possible to use `%`, `|`, all sorts of characters, but in consideration to any others who might use the file on a different system the question becomes "should we?" Just because we can? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7351 has some interesting thoughts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically I believe that is possible, though this way to split code is not conventional and the solution includes more vinegar than sugar :).

First, you need to tell Zeitwerk to [ignore those files](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#ignoring-parts-of-the-project). For example, in an initializer you can do this:

```
# ignore accepts a glob pattern.
Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore("god~*")
```

Second, you need to `load` the files, so that reloading interprets them again:

```
class God < ApplicationRecord
  load "#{__dir__}/god~callbacks.rb"
  ...
end
```

I assume those files are not loaded in other places, so idempotence does not matter. If it matters, then you need some extra vinegar.

The solution above is untested, but you see the idea.

It is an unusual way to split code, you know that, normally you use modules and the name of the module reflects what the code is organizing, which is what the file names are doing. I'd recommend going with modules. But if you want to keep that style, in principle you can, though the solution is a bit forced.

Comment: Thanks a lot Xavier — I've got the idea.

Comment: Xavier - is `load` preferable to `require_dependency` under zeitwerk? Rails guides say `require_dependency` should be deprecated, but it still seems like it... works. (It seems like refactoring something like this into modules, you have to separate the instance methods of each file into one module, and the class methods in another, for each split file. That would make for a lot of split files... not to mention the headache of updating the name of every call to those methods.)

Comment: Yes, in this case it is preferable because you don't want idempotence, and `Kernel#load` is just Ruby, no need to reach for anything else. `require_dependency` is there mostly for backwards compatibility, and because engines may need to support classic in Rails 6.

Answer (score 2):

You can opt out of using Zeitwerk by setting `config.autoload = :classic` in your `application.rb` file. If you want to continue using Zeitwerk, then why not replace the `require_dependency` calls with `include`?

Comment: Sure, I know that it's possible to opt out of Zeitwerk, and that's what I'm doing for now. `include` can not be used because (a) those files don't define any modules, they reopen the class instead and (b) even if they do define a module Zeitwerk will search for a nested module in a subdirectory, custom naming schemes are not supported.

Comment: Note that this should be `config.autoloader = :classic`